# How can I pass a List<string> to an api url?

Tags: api

Suppose I have an api method like this inside `MyAPIS` controller:

```
public List<string> GetList(List<string> myList)
{
    var newList = myList;
    return newList;
}
```

The uri bind to this action should be something like mysite/api/myapis/getlist/[id]. Usually the id is a single value and not a complex item.
But how'd you manage to arrage an url like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to be more specific about what framework you are using to get a specific answer. However, in essence what you want to accomplish is the use of `slugs`.  Depending on what framework you are using you can just search for :  "framework" slug, "framework" slugs, "framework" slugify.

For example this explains how to use slugs on a controller with the Spring MVC framework:

https://github.com/resthub/resthub.org/blob/master/spring-stack.rst#sluggable-controller

Hope this helps.